# Increase hit Area of button

Tags: android

I want to increase the hit area of an expand/collapse button. I do not want to provide extra padding for the button which will look odd. Any valuable suggestion would help.

Comment: what you have tried for this. please show us.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [TouchDelegate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TouchDelegate.html)

There is a tutorial on the [dev docs](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please use **ImageButton** instead of **Button** and give **Padding "5"** in all side. So, it's not become blured image and look like good.

Comment: But i dont want any extra padding around the image.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to put some text on the `Button`, so you cannot go for an `ImageButton`, if you're using a drawable for your `Button background`, you could just add the padding to the drawable png itself.